# How do I calculate the dividend yield for Disney Co?

Tags: stocks, calculation, dividends, rate-of-return, yield

I'm trying to "estimate" the dividend yield for Disney (`NYSE:DIS`). Let's pretend stock price will stay at $57 and the tax rate is 1%. Is it really the case that after 3 years with this stock the return is 17%?! Seems too high. After 3 years supposedly i will make $4000, which is 70% of my initial investment (100 shares @ $57 ea). Incredible.

Also, for year 1, why does it say Dividends are $75, and then Dividends earned are $430? I see where $75 comes from, but what's $430?

I'm using calculator at [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/calculator/divcyield.aspx). Here's a link to better [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWUBh.png)

[image]

Comment: You have put in the yearly dividend as quarterly dividend.

Answer (score 3):

DIS has a .75 dividend per year. It's a bit over 1.3% per year. I don't follow the rest of your math, sorry.

It takes a few second's effort to see the [dividend is annual](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=DIS&a=00&b=2&c=1962&d=03&e=4&f=2013&g=v).

[image]

Comment: 0.75 per year or per quarter??

Comment: I edited my answer. Although I did say per year, I now list the dividend distributions the past few years.